# jBPM: process deployment via API

Tags: java, jbpm

I have create a business process flow using fluent API. I have few questions:

1. With fluent API I am able to create a new process flow and validate it. But after build where that file (*.bpmn) is getting created?

```
RuleFlowProcessFactory factory = RuleFlowProcessFactory.createProcess("org.jbpm.HelloWorld");
factory
    .name("HelloWorldProcess")
    .version("1.0")
    .packageName("org.jbpm")
    .startNode(1).name("Start").done()
    .endNode(2).name("End").done()
    // Connections
    .connection(1, 2)
    .build();
```

Where HelloWorld.bpmn file will be created?

2. Is there a way to create the process flow (*.bpmn file) inside kJar file with some API?
3. Even if I somehow create a process using fluent API, how can I deploy it to a already existing kie server. I have a kie server running on localhost:8080, so is there a way to deploy the process created with fluent API on my kie-server.
4. If not possible, is there a way to deploy the kJar to kie-server without using the business central. Is there any API for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For executing a process, you should create a `Resource`, which is used to create a `KieBase`. Using that `KieBase`, you can create a `KieSession` to execute the process.

Using `ProcessBuilderFactory.toBytes` for that process definition will create a ByteArrayResource resource.

```
// Build resource from Process
KieResources resources = ServiceRegistry.getInstance().get(KieResources.class);
Resource res = resources                         
                        .newByteArrayResource(factory.toBytes(process))
```

Or, in your case, from the `RuleFlowProcess` process:

```
Resource res = ResourceFactory
               .newByteArrayResource(
                  XmlBPMNProcessDumper.INSTANCE.dump(process).getBytes());
```

`kieModule` is automatically deployed to `KieRepository` if successfully built with `buildAll()`.

Take a look at the following example:

```
// source path or target path must be set to be added into kbase                       
res.setSourcePath("/tmp/processFactory.bpmn2"); 

​
// Build kie base from this resource using KIE API
​KieServices ks = KieServices.Factory.get();
​KieRepository kr = ks.getRepository();
​KieFileSystem kfs = ks.newKieFileSystem();
​kfs.write(res);
​KieBuilder kb = ks.newKieBuilder(kfs);

// kieModule is automatically deployed to KieRepository if successfully built.
​kb.buildAll(); 

​KieContainer kContainer = ks.newKieContainer(kr.getDefaultReleaseId());
​KieBase kbase = kContainer.getKieBase();
​
// Create kie session using KieBase
​KieSessionConfiguration conf = ...;
​Environment env = ....;
​KieSession ksession = kbase.newKieSession(conf,env);

​// execute process using same process Id that is used to obtain ProcessBuilder instance
​ksession.startProcess("org.jbpm.HelloWorld")
```